# Bringing in call UI in front using adb command

Tags: android, adb

**Use case**

during a phone call, User opened some apps and the inCall UI goes behind the APP UI.I need to bring it back using adb command

What i did ?

I used below command

```
adb shell am start --activity-brought-to-front -n com.google.android.dialer/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity
```

Which resulted in error

```
Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.
google.android.dialer/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity } from null (pid=12862
, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10102

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10400000
 cmp=com.google.android.dialer/com.android.incallui.InCallActivity } from null (
pid=12862, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10102
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPe
```

Is there any way to acheive the desired result using adb?

Comment: @iVoid is there a way to do this without root permission?

Comment: Please ignore, I'm not sure if it is related to `root` permission.

Answer (score 2):

The [`InCallActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/pie-release/java/com/android/incallui/AndroidManifest.xml#58) activity can't be launched from other applications including launching via `am start` as the [`android:exported`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported) element of `InCallActivity` is set to `false`.

> **android:exported**
>
> This element sets whether the activity can be launched by components of other applications - "true" if it can be, and "false" if
>   not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of
>   the same application or applications with the same user ID.
>
> If you are using intent filters, you should not set this element "false". If you do so, and an app tries to call the activity, system
>   throws an ActivityNotFoundException. Instead, you should prevent other
>   apps from calling the activity by not setting intent filters for it.
>
> If you do not have intent filters, the default value for this element is "false". If you set the element "true", the activity is
>   accessible to any app that knows its exact class name, but does not
>   resolve when the system tries to match an implicit intent.
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the
>   external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission
>   attribute).

Comment: This element is a part of `AndroidManifest.xml` of the app you're trying to launch - `InCallActivity`/`incallui` app. You can't do it unless you can change the app itself.